# How to store per date data in Redis

Tags: redis

Our company currently has a PSQL database and we work with data that is similar to Airbnb.

For example we have a lot of date base information such as

Price per day

Availability (whether a space is available or not for a specific date)

Example
Space 1

Today
$99
Available

Tomorrow
$129
Available

After tomorrow
Not available

This information is constantly changing, we use Psql without any problems, but we would like to introduce Redis for caching this information and only updating redis once these specific information changes for each specific date, this way we can only update the necessary parts and optimize the backend to submit to redis every time something changes.

My biggest concert is how to store the per date data in an effective way

And how to store the relationship between the space and its info, as there can be millions of other spaces with their own per date data and "rows"

Tried multiple options such as Redis sorted sets, time series and Redis Json, and Redis text search.

Sorted sets and time series do not help. And json and textsearch does not seem to make full use of the power of redis and easy enought to only obtain the dates needed for computing the answer to the query

Comment: Can you give some examples for the kind of queries you want to make? RediSearch and RedisTimeSeries can be used to store and query based on time-stamps. Can you explain what’s missing for your use case?

Comment: @A.Guy
The idea would be for example:

for space1 give me the prices and availability status from 2023-05-10 to 2023-06-10

RedisSearch allows for good SQL like querying but I am not sure if it is possible to update in the same way and if it will use all the power of Redis to make it as simple as possible to "process" and deliver

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Redis `hashmaps` to store the space information:
From the example that you have given above, you can run:

```
hmset space1 2023-05-24-price 99 2023-05-24-status available 2023-05-25-price 129 2023-05-25-status available 2023-04-26-status not-available
```

This will create a hash-map `space1` with key-value pairs inside it.
So, if you have to get the status of any date for `space1`, you can run:

```
> hget space1 2023-04-26-status
"not-available"
```

Similarly, if you want to know the price of `space1` on some particular day, you can run:

```
> hget space1 2023-05-24-price
"99"
```

If you want to update any price, you can use the same `hset` command.

For deleting any key inside space1, you can use `hdel` command.

To get all the information about space1, you can use `hgetall` command

For fetching multiple keys from space1, you can use hmget, like this:
To fetch availability and price of date 2023-05-24:

```
> hmget space1 2023-05-24-status 2023-05-24-price
1) "available"
2) "99"
```

To get price of 2023-05-24 and 2023-05-25:

```
> hmget space1 2023-05-24-price 2023-05-25-price
1) "99"
2) "129"
```

Comment: If you go this route, you could then use the Search capability in Redis Stack to index these values and perform more SQL like queries over them. https://redis.io/docs/stack/search/

Comment: Ankit thanks for your patience and time!

This is a really possible and interesting solution

I see that it offers a good way to update this data fast and easy, however the only part I do not like is that I have to fetch the entire data if I want to get the availability and or price for a small date range

As I believe Redis is great for this, this would be probably simpler and easier then redis search, but I would have to consume more data on the backend and filter out, as most of the time I would get more data then what necessary on the query

Comment: @SimonPrickett
This is the method that I have enjoyed the most, but my problem lies in updating this data, can the same RedisSearch to update these values?

Comment: @annkit

Unless it is possible to pull multiple dates prices and availabilities in the hget 

Not sure if something like this is possible

Comment: You don't need to fetch the entire data just for the sake of 1 or 2 keys, I am updating my answer to reflect the changes

Comment: @Nuclear RediSearch doesn't do update queries at this time, you'd need to take the resultset and send updates back to Redis yourself.  You could do this atomically as a transaction or with a Lua script if needed.

Comment: @SimonPrickett that solves it perfectly, thats for your help this i Believe is the most efficient and intelligent way to use all the power of redis for setting and getting this data thank you very much fot your help

Comment: Please do accept the answer if you are happy with it! :)